# iptables masquerading and rejecting outside-to-inside

Tags: iptables, nat

I found [masquerading made simple howto](http://linuxdoc.org/HOWTO/Masquerading-Simple-HOWTO/summary.html) very useful and everything works just fine. But I'm not sure about the last line:

```
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -i ! ppp0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP   #only if the first two are succesful
iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o ppp0 -j REJECT
```

There is no explanation in the howto. Why is that for?

I guess it's to reject outside-to-inside traffic, but how it works? Maybe it's better to write `-i ppp0 -o eth0` (where eth0 is my local network interface)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FORWARD` table is used to manage packets that are being routed though the box. That rule basically stops anything being routed via the ppp0 interface.

Comment: i still don't understand. My laptop is connected to internet through pc with that configuration.

Comment: iptables works from top down so anything that hasn't been previously matched with respect to the FORWARD table will be rejected by that rule.

Comment: oh, i get it. Thanks. Is it better to drop instead of reject?